# Visual Studio 2010, TFS keeps checking out solution file changing 'VWDPort'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2010, every time I open my project, TFS checks out the solution file. When I perform a TFS compare, the only difference I see is a change to variable called `VWDPort`. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

EDIT: I found what appears to be a solution: [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/233094/compilation-change-the-vwdport-parameter-in-the-sln-file-painful-with-source-control). However, I don't understand what the poster means by 'project properties grid', and I have been unable to find the options described.

Answer (score 2):

From http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/233094/compilation-change-the-vwdport-parameter-in-the-sln-file-painful-with-source-control:

"This behavior is by design, but there is a workaround. You should be able to specify a port number in the project property grid and then set "Use dynamic ports" to false, so the port number never changes."

Comment: I just found this, but I can't find the menu option that is being described and I don't know that the responder means by 'Project Property Grid'. I tried right-clicking the solution file and looking at 'properties', couldn't find it.

Comment: My guess is that if you open the project properties for the web application and switch to the Web tab you probably have 'Use Visual Studio Development Server' selected. Auto-assign Port is also selected. Change it to Specific port.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compilation change the VWDPort option in your .sln file

Comment: Ok... how would I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010

- Select your 'Web Site' in solution explorer (I assume it was created with File -> New Website)
- Open good old standard properties window (View -> Properties Window)
- 'Use dynamic ports' set to 'False'

No checked out solution files ever since.

P.S. The tricky part was that the 'properties grid' is usually for WebApplications not old WebSites templates.